# On form submit, mailto from javascript with form values

Tags: javascript, jquery, mailto

I have a form, and when the form is submitted (input type="submit"), i would like to open the clients default mail-browser with a pre-populated email-message.

So when the user clicks submit two things need to happen. Open email and submit form.

Also, how can i use the values entered in the form to prepopulate the email?

I'm new to javascript-jquery so please, any code example would be of great help!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You want...javascript to handle this? I would prefer PHP at least.

Comment: The thing is that i cant use serverside emailing, because one of the requirements is that the email must be sent from the clients own email client so that the message will appear in his outbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before submitting the form you could do:

```
 window.location.href = 'mailto:nicola@mio.it';
```

this will open the predefined mail client and you can also prefill some field. look at the mailto sintax [here](http://www.ianr.unl.edu/internet/mailto.html) or post some more info so that we can help you;

This could be done like this :

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function(){
     window.location.href = "mailto:" + $('#email').val();
});
```

Comment: So i am looking at something like this then: `code`<input type="submit" onclick="javascript:Email()" class="submit" value="Submit"/>`code`

Comment: aha. Thanks again. Just saw your new example. That example will continue to submit the form after the mailto has been opened?

Comment: Yes of course it will submit. If you look at the link you will see that you can also prepopulate some fields like the body of the message

Comment: Yep. That one i figured out by myself :) Thanks a lot. You have been very helpful. Btw. can i fill the body with html to style the body?

Comment: No i don't think (at least i tried with this `window.location.href = 'mailto:astark1@unl.edu?body=<b>I am having trouble finding information on</b>';` and it didn't work! :)

Answer (score 1):

I have used a code like this when I needed to send via mailto using my local email client, it may help:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="myform" enctype="text/plain" action="test.php" method="post" >
 <input type="text" value="value1" id ="field1" name="field1">
 <input type="checkbox" value="valuel2" id ="field2" name="field2" checked>
 <input type="checkbox" value="value3" id ="field3" name="field3" >
 <textarea id="myText" name ="texty">
     Lorem ipsum...
 </textarea>
 <button onclick="sendMail(); return false">Send</button>
</form>
<script>
function sendMail() {
 $myform = $('#myform');
 $myform.prop ('action','mailto:mymail@mydomain.es');
 $myform.submit();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can prepopulate form with

```
$("textarea").val('Your message here! You\' have to strip \'');
```

---

if it's default email clien't, I'm afraid it's not possible

Comment: I wouldn't recommend JS for mailing form values after submittion.

Comment: he doesn't want to send a mail, he wants to open the default mail client i think

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti: aaha! So it isn't possible :/

Comment: @Genesis, no no it's possible. It's a little bit old as a tecnique

Comment: @Genesis: I dont wont to prepopulate the form. I only want to grab the values from the form.