# Simultaneously open mailto and submit form

Tags: javascript, html, mailto

At management's request, I need to open the user's email client and submit a form on a button click.  I initially had

```
window.location = "mailto:email@example.com";
```

as the callback to the click event for the submit input, but this doesn't work.  It seems like the form submits to quickly.

Using `window.open` does work, but it creates a blank window that is undesirable.

I also had the idea to prevent and delay the form submission as in

```
window.location = "mailto:personalcounselor@gleim.com";
setTimeout(function () { 
    $(this).closest('form').trigger('submit');
}.bind(this), 1000); 
e.preventDefault();
```

This also works, but it seems sketchy to me.

Is there any way to submit the form and open a mailto link at the same time?

Comment: assuming you are trying to submit the form ( which will cause a postback ), there are a few reasonable options... 
1) change your submission functionality to an ajax method that causes your expected behavior on success
2) create a hidden link that you trigger a click on with an href="mailto:email@example.com"..

Comment: @BrettWeber that's a possible solution, but it would still cause a delay (they would have to wait for the request to complete).  I'd rather have the browser show the visible delay of the form submission

Comment: sorry for prematurely adding that comment, edited to show another option. as an afterthought, have you tried changing the html by wrapping the submit button in a link that has the mailto href?

Comment: @BrettWeber no ... would that actually work???  Trying it now

Comment: @BrettWeber doesn't seem like it worked, but interesting thought

Comment: I have no idea, but that will be a great thing to test. I do not have my environment up right now, but please, post your results if they work as an answer! I would surely enjoy knowing if it does, as this would be a very useful trick to implement.

Comment: hrm.. ok.. Well, If none of those routes work, I'll keep running through the possible routes until I can come up with something.. Is it possible to instigate this from the server? or in the submit action on the form?... this is difficult because of the nature of the synchronous operation order. GriffLab's answer may work better than either of these.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will work, but I am sure with a bit of tweaking it should work and have the desired result which you are after (it was too long to fit in a comment, if it will not work I will gladly delete it!);

```
$("form").on("submit", function() {
     window.onbeforeunload = function() {
         window.location = "mailto:email@example.com";
     };
});
```

Simply put when the form is submitted, set the `onbeforeunload` event to change the location to the mailto. I think doing it this way will only make the mailto open if the form is submitted rather than when a user just navigates away.

I don't know if this will work, or how hacky it is, but thought I would throw in my two cents!

**UPDATE**

[On form submit, mailto from javascript with form values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882355/on-form-submit-mailto-from-javascript-with-form-values)

This does seem to work and verified by others.

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function(){
     window.location.href = "mailto:email@example.com";
});
```

Comment: Seems like a great attempt, but it doesn't work for me.  I don't have the client already open, so maybe that makes a difference.  I'll test this out more tomorrow

Comment: I will have a few more attempts at trying to get this to work for you, if I get a solution I'll post it up.